# This is 2d string array I want search details using id how i can do

Tags: java

```
public class Source
{ 
 String[][]customerDetails=new String[5][3];

 Source()
 {
  customerDetails[0][0]="1001":
  customerDetails[0][1]="Raj"; 
  customerDetails[0][2]="Chenna";

  customerDetails[1][0]="1008"; 
  customerDetails[1][1]="Akshay";
  customerDetails[1][2]="Pune";

  customerDetails[2][0]="1002";
  customerDetails[2][1]="Simrath"; 
  customerDetails[2][2]="Amristar";

  customerDetails[3][0]="1204";
  customerDetails[3][1]="Gaurav";
  customerDetails[3][2]="Delhi";

  customerDetails[4][0]="1805";
  customerDetails[4][1]="Ganesh";
  customerDetails[4][2]="Chennai";
 }

 public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception 
 {
  Source src=new Source();
 }
}
```

Comment: Your code won't even compile. Are you having compilation errors?

Comment: Please format your code.

Comment: Now check again

Comment: When presenting your code in StackOverflow you should at the very least provide it error free. It shows that you actually care whether or not a solution can be acquired and those that are going to assist you don't need to waste time correcting it. If you don't care...why should anyone else?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to get Customer Details based on a supplied Customer ID (read comments in code):

```
String[][]customerDetails = new String[5][3];
customerDetails[0][0]="1001";
customerDetails[0][1]="Raj";
customerDetails[0][2]="Chenna";
customerDetails[1][0]="1008";
customerDetails[1][1]="Akshay";
customerDetails[1][2]="Pune";
customerDetails[2][0]="1002";
customerDetails[2][1]="Simrath";
customerDetails[2][2]="Amristar";
customerDetails[3][0]="1204";
customerDetails[3][1]="Gaurav";
customerDetails[3][2]="Delhi";
customerDetails[4][0]="1805";
customerDetails[4][1]="Ganesh";
customerDetails[4][2]="Chennai";
    
// Scanner object to get keyboard input from User.
Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in); 
    
// Prompt loop. Keep looping until 'q' is entered to quit.
while (true) {
    System.out.print("Enter a four digit ID number (q to quit): --> ");
    String idNum = userInput.nextLine();  // Get User input...
    // If 'q' is entered then quit.
    if (idNum.equalsIgnoreCase("q")) {
        System.out.println("Bye-Bye");
        break;
    }
    /* VALIDATE input. Make sure it's a 4 digit numerical value.
       If it isn't then inform User of Invalid Entry and allow 
       the User to try again.            */
    if (!idNum.matches("[0-9]{4}")) {
        System.out.println("Invalid ID Number (" + idNum + ")! Try Again...\n");
        continue;
    }
       
    // Display ID details...
    boolean found = false; // Flag to indicate that Customer ID was found.
    for (String[] customer : customerDetails) {
        if (customer[0].equals(idNum)) {
            System.out.println("Customer ID:\t" + customer[0]);
            System.out.println("Customer Name:\t" + customer[1]);
            System.out.println("Customer City:\t" + customer[2]);
            System.out.println();
            found = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!found) {
        // If Customer ID was not found!
        System.out.println("Can not find the Customer ID (" + idNum 
                         + ") within the Customers List!\n");
    }
}
```